# google maps js : create tour

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i need to create a webpage with html and javascript that show the user a tour from America to Jordan.

i checked the Javascrip API for Google but i did not find a tour option.

i.e. give coordinates for 2 locations with speed and scroll the map between these 2 locations.

Comment: So you want to create a route between this two points or just scroll the map from one point to the other?

Comment: it is something like plane tour ... scroll the map between America and jordan when reach jordan zoom in.

Comment: @user712215: I think you have to describe your problem better... e.g. I still don't understand what is a "tour" for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this directly on google maps. Create the tour, you put in 'signs' which are generally text but can be links or pictures also. Then when finished you get a link to your tour that you can use to insert into a web page.

Comment: i want it as plane tour ... i tried to record the tour using google earth but the reselution was very low.